# System.Drawing.Bitmap to Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap

Tags: bitmap, uwp

**Background**

I'm trying to create some app that runs in mixed reality portal. It should therefore be an UWP app. To overcome the restrictive model of UWP I let it consume a WCF service. In that WCF service I have more control.

**Question:**

In the WCF service I get a screenshot from an application that I want to show in the UWP app. The screenshot comes as a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. The UWP app does not know of this type, hence I need to use something else. I think I can use a `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap`. So I need a conversion. I can not for the life of me find out how to do it. I tried BitmapEncoder. But then I need `Windows.Foundations.FoundationContracts` in the WCF service, which is not in the list of assemblies to reference. how can I go from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap`?

Comment: There is a lot you can get done in UWP, especially as it gets more and more capable with every release, it is just the API is different. But the UI is based on XAML, so in terms of controls and UI-related APIs there are a lot of similarities.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is rather [`Windows.UI.XAML.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) which is quite similar to the `BitmapImage.SetSource` method to get an image from a given stream, which should be possible to create from your `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.